# Finding edge weights that balance node values

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am dealing with a graph where nodes have associated values that could be positive or negative. I need to assign weights to the edges of this graph so that my network is 'balanced.' For example, if I have a graph with two nodes, with values of +10 and -10, and my adjacency matrix is:

```
0   1
1   0
```

I need to figure out how to assign weights to those edges like:

```
0   10
0   0
```

so that the resulting transport will 'neutralize' the values at my nodes.

A more complex example is a graph that looks like:

```
-10 -- 0 -- +20
       |
       0
       |
      -10
```

would get described in an adjacency matrix that would look like:

```
0   10  0   0   0
0   0   20  0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   10  0   0   0
0   0   0   10  0
```

Are there any well known solutions to this problem?

Comment: How 'neutralizing' works in your examples? Give some paths examples describing how are they 'neutralized',

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  The mechanics of your application are not clear.

Comment: Thanks @Yola, in the second example, the adjacency matrix should be 'transporting' positive charge to negative charge in ways that all nodes should finish with a value of 0. So the solution should have +20 flowing from the upper right node to the upper center node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a max-flow calculation by connecting all negative-charged links to a 'sink' with links that have maximum capacities corresponding to their charges, and connecting all positive-charged nodes to a source with links that have maximum capacities corresponding to the node charge. In the process of calculating the maximum amount of flow between the source and the sink the adjacency matrix records the flows along links.

I used the Edmonds Karp algorithm specifically.